# win:length(2) is fired after first event

Tags: esper

I made a very simple test gui based on [this brilliant article](http://coffeeonesugar.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/getting-started-with-esper-in-5-minutes) about getting started with Esper.

What surprises me is that this query is validated to true after the very first tick event is sent, **if the price is above 6**.

```
select * from StockTick(symbol='AAPL').win:length(2) having avg(price) > 6.0
```

As far as I understand, **win:length(2)** needs **TWO ticks** before an event is fired, or am I wrong?

Here is a SSCCE for this question, just press the "Create Tick Event" button and you will see the StockTick Event being fired at once.

[image]

It needs the following jars which comes bundled with [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper/download/download.html)

```
esper\lib\antlr-runtime-3.2.jar
esper\lib\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
esper\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
esper\lib\esper_3rdparties.license
esper\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar
esper-4.11.0.jar
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

import com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPAdministrator;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPRuntime;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProvider;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatement;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EventBean;
import com.espertech.esper.client.UpdateListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Tester extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton createRandomValueEventButton;

    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel southPanel;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private static JTextArea centerTextArea;
    private static JTextArea southTextArea;
    private static Random generator = new Random();

    private EPRuntime cepRT;
    private JSplitPane textSplitPane;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    private static JTextField priceTextField;

    public Tester() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();

        createRandomValueEventButton = new JButton("Create Tick Event With Random Price");
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(createRandomValueEventButton);
        createRandomValueEventButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                createTickWithRandomPrice();
            }
        });

        panel = new JPanel();
        splitPane.setRightComponent(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        btnNewButton = new JButton("Create Tick Event");
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                createTick();
            }
        });

        priceTextField = new JTextField();
        priceTextField.setText(new Integer(10).toString());
        panel.add(priceTextField);
        priceTextField.setColumns(4);
        getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        textSplitPane = new JSplitPane();
        textSplitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        getContentPane().add(textSplitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));


        JScrollPane centerTextScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        centerTextScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        centerTextArea = new JTextArea();
        centerTextArea.setRows(12);
        centerTextScrollPane.setViewportView(centerTextArea);

        southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JScrollPane southTextScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        southTextScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        southTextArea = new JTextArea();
        southTextArea.setRows(5);
        southTextScrollPane.setViewportView(southTextArea);

        textSplitPane.setRightComponent(southTextScrollPane);
        textSplitPane.setLeftComponent(centerTextScrollPane);

        setupCEP();
    }

    public static void GenerateRandomTick(EPRuntime cepRT) {     
        double price = (double) generator.nextInt(10);
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String symbol = "AAPL";
        Tick tick = new Tick(symbol, price, timeStamp);
        System.out.println("Sending tick:" + tick);
        centerTextArea.append(new Date().toString()+"     Sending tick:" + tick+"\n");
        cepRT.sendEvent(tick);

    }

    public static void GenerateTick(EPRuntime cepRT) {       
        double price = Double.parseDouble(priceTextField.getText());
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String symbol = "AAPL";
        Tick tick = new Tick(symbol, price, timeStamp);
        System.out.println("Sending tick:" + tick);
        centerTextArea.append(new Date().toString()+"     Sending tick: " + tick+"\n");
        cepRT.sendEvent(tick);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tester tester = new Tester();
        tester.setSize(new Dimension(570,500));
        tester.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createTickWithRandomPrice(){   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GenerateRandomTick(getEPRuntime());
            }
        }); 
    }

    private void createTick(){  
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GenerateTick(getEPRuntime());
            }
        }); 
    }

    private void setupCEP(){        
        Configuration cepConfig = new Configuration();
        cepConfig.addEventType("StockTick", Tick.class.getName());
        EPServiceProvider cep = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("myCEPEngine", cepConfig);
        cepRT = cep.getEPRuntime();

        EPAdministrator cepAdm = cep.getEPAdministrator();
        EPStatement cepStatement = cepAdm.createEPL(
                "select * from " +
                "StockTick(symbol='AAPL').win:length(2) " +
                "having avg(price) > 6.0");

        cepStatement.addListener(new CEPListener());
        //System.out.println("cepStatement.getText(): "+cepStatement.getText());
    }

    private EPRuntime getEPRuntime(){

    public static class Tick {
            String symbol;
            Double price;
            Date timeStamp;

            public Tick(String s, double p, long t) {
                symbol = s;
                price = p;
                timeStamp = new Date(t);
            }
            public double getPrice() {return price;}
            public String getSymbol() {return symbol;}
            public Date getTimeStamp() {return timeStamp;}

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return symbol+" Price: " + price.toString();
            }
    }

    public static class CEPListener implements UpdateListener {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually aggregation and conditions are independent of how many events are in data window. There are functions you could use to check whether a data window is "filled": the "leaving", "count" or "prevcount" for example.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested,

changing the query to this solved the problem

```
select * from StockTick(symbol='AAPL').win:length_batch(2) having avg(price) > 6.0 and count(*) >= 2
```

Now an event will be triggered for every consecutive tick with the price higher than 6, in batches of two.